# Site doesn't call AJAX, doesn't give error, used to do before

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

It seems that my site doesn't do the ajax call. Which it used to do before i modified my code, but i'm not sure what i did. The function call is correct as it does the first alert. Is it my syntax that is wrong? or am i missing something. Im fairly new to JS as well.

```
<script>
        function dologin() {
            var pdata = $('#form').serialize();
            alert(pdata);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost/Hovedprosjekt/public/phonegap',
                data: {
                    email:'test@test.no',
                    password:'test'
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function() {     
                    console.log(data);
                    alert("error");
                } 
            });
            return false;
        };
</script>
```

EDIT:

Here is the server code that receives the data.

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <!-- {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address') }} -->
    <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["email"])) echo $_POST['email'];?>">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }} -->
        <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["password"])) echo $_POST['password'];?>">
</div>
```

EDIT2:

Here's the form below the JS.

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="dologin()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Epost</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="test@test.no" placeholder="Epost">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">    
        <label for="password">Passord</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="test" placeholder="Passord">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me">
        Husk meg
        </label>
    </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Logg inn</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: what domain is your script launched from? You try to call to localhost, is this JS run from localhost too?

Comment: ajax code looks good need to see your server side stuff!

Comment: Press F12, find the script console and see if you got any errors. The syntax seems to be fine, so it could be anything.

Comment: maybe try to put `http://` before `localhost`. It probably tries to call a directory relatively called `localhost`

Comment: As @KeluThatsall mentioned, it is happening because you didn't put http:// . Your script is trying to get data from a relative url.

Comment: Oh, the URL is set to my server, http://something.com/Hovedprosjekt/public/phonegap

According to F12 console, and the network tab the ajax isnt being called on or run at all.

Comment: Show us the fragment of the code where you call `doLogin` function

Comment: does the url http://something.com/Hovedprosjekt/public/phonegap as the same domain than your app (not http://www.something.com ) ?

Comment: I mean `http://something.com/Hovedprosjekt/public/phonegap` is not in the same domain than  `http://www.something.com`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `http://` before `localhost`.

The script tries to call a directory relatively called `localhost`

As a proof on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48H6G/) it tries to connect to:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/localhost/Hovedprosjekt/public/phonegap

If you change the `url` property to: `url: 'http://localhost/Hovedprosjekt/public/phonegap',` then it should be fine (considering you are running this on localhost).

Comment: I tried and it didnt work. Usually I have http:// and the full server link in the url

Comment: You should show us then when you call the `doLogin` function cause you might be doing that wrong way.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add it right away. Please see the new edited post.

Answer (score 0):

the line

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="dologin()">
```

should be replaced by

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return dologin();">
```

because it's the way to disable the submit (an expression which return false).

Currently it don't disable the submit so what you see is a refresh of your page which cancel the ajax call.